# Nodejs child process output in parent

Tags: node.js

I have been able to use various Nodejs child process functions to get output from child to parent if I use the command 'node --version' in the child process and the data event is fired, the parent gets the output. However when I run an executable like lmutil.exe for flexnet, the executable produces the output which is visible on the console however the output does not get transferred to the parent. The data event is never fired and the stdout is always undefined. Has anyone encountered similar situation.

Tried various child process functions exec, spawn and their sync versions but face the same issue.

```
let ls =spawn('lmutil.exe', ['lmstat','-a','-c','27000@localhost']);

ls.stdout.on('data', function(data){
    console.log('data event fired');
}
```

Comment: Did you check to see if the output was going to `stderr` or maybe the output is going from lmstat to the console, but not through lmutil which is the child that you are monitoring?  This looks like you're running a child of a child and expecting the 2nd child's output to come back through the first child's stdout, but that is perhaps not how lmutil works.

Comment: Yes, no events are fired apart from the exit event on the child. The same code works with something simple like node --version'. You could be right that the lmutil executable might not be working as expected. Just trying to follow and create simpler Verizon of https://github.com/quantumhpc/flexlmjs/blob/master/flexjs.js

Comment: Yeah, so I think lmutil is just running the child as a child, but not getting the child's output itself.  The child's output is going to it's own stdout which goes to the console.  Perhaps there is some way (with command line arguments or some other means) to pipe the output from whatever lmutil is running to lmutil's stdout so you can then capture it?

Comment: Lmutil lmstat returns stats of license usage. This is what the utility exe does lmstat is just an option/argument.

Comment: Then, you have to somehow figure out why lmutil is not sending any output to stdout or stderr.  You can start by registering listeners for the `error` and `close` event on `ls` and listening for `data` on stderr, none of which you show in your code.

Comment: I have error event listener as well however that too isn't invoked. Trying something simpler I can run the lmutil.exe lmstats command on the command line and get the output fine. However trying to send the output to a text file doesn't work. Not too sure if that could be a permission issue. By default executing an exe file produced output to the console window and to redirect the output to a log file we can use lmutil.exe lmstat -a -c > data.txt however that too doesn't work

Comment: Perhaps you should add the examples that do work and the examples that don't work to your question as I can't keep track of what exactly you've said does and doesn't work.  The `>` character isn't going to work with spawn.  You'd have to launch a command shell because it's in a command shell that `>` is processed.

Comment: Sure, just to reiterate running on the command line, the lmutil.exe command works as expected and outputs the result to the console. Now trying to redirect the same output to a file using > doesn't work and the new file is just empty. I am wondering if this is due to some permission issue. The file does get generated but is empty. Keeping this simple case in mind for now, could there be any other reason for lmutil.exe to not produce the output to a file.

Comment: Yes, if the thing that lmutil.exe is running doesn't send its output back to lmutil.

Comment: Ok that's the confusing but how does it then display it on console and I have seen python and nodejs code using same technique